# Setting up ruby on rails gem ga_events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I am relatively new to web dev and I am trying to set up the ruby on rails gem ga_events (https://github.com/Nix-wie-weg/ga_events). I am doing this because I need to have google analytics event tracking within controllers and this gem seems like a good way to do it. The issue I am having is where the readme says, "After requiring ga_events.js, you have to choose an adapter." I am using Google Universal Analytics and thus I would like to choose that one. It doesn't say specifically how to do this. Where do I put that code block (https://github.com/Nix-wie-weg/ga_events#google-universal-analytics-analyticsjs)? Do I need to make a new file somewhere?

I'm assuming it's obvious for a more experienced developer. More detailed instructions+explanation would be really helpful. Thanks.

I'm using Rails 4.0.13 and Ruby 2.0.0p643.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue here! Turns out, it is just javascript code.

I put mine under `application.js` since it's a code that need to be on every page.